# Difference between subdomains `WWW` and `m`

Tags: web, mobile, subdomain

What's the difference between these two subdomains ***WWW*** and ***m***? 
For instance, **`WWW.medium.com`** and **`m.medium.com`**

In my country, `WWW.medium.com` is blocked, but when I try using `m.medium.com` instead, It works well. So I want to know what's the difference between them? Can they have different content?

**PS:** I have searched about that, but haven't found anything related 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can. In fact, the two domains [www.medium.com](http://www.medium.com) and m.medium.com could point to two completely different servers. This is up to the owner of medium.com to decide.

Usually, a 'm' subdomain points to the version of the site that is intended for mobile devices, i.e. devices with a smaller screen size.

Pinging the domains, I get 162.159.153.4 for medium.com, 162.159.152.4 for [www.medium.com](http://www.medium.com) and 162.159.152.4 for m.medium.com.